# What is the minimal installation to run .NET application created in C# by monodevelop?

Tags: 12.04, package-management, mono, monodevelop, c#

I am a bit noobish when it comes to .NET but I am wondering what is the bare minimum of packages needed to be installed to run .NET application. It is a simple input output console app and with command:

> app_name.exe

it runs on my computer but when I try to run it on another computer (which doesn't have monodevelop and all that stuff) it returns error:

> cannot execute binary file

so I am wondering what are the minimum in terms of size packages that need to be installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have installed `mono-runtime` to run .NET/Mono applications, plus Wine if they use Windows specifics.

Comment: I noticed that if I install monodevelop I can run app but if there is only mono-runtime this error appears again, my app uses only some basic System.IO methods and nothing else. Is there some library or something like that i need to install?

Comment: You can try installing `libmono-microsoft-csharp-4.0-cil`.